# Which API is DatePicker changed?

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm designing a big android project. 5 months ago I have designed a good UI by editing Datepicker like this:

[image: The Datepicker with + and - buttons]

But after I changed my computer and moved project to new computer, I get an error on getChildAt(int). Then I removed all modifications on it and saw the datepicker like this :

[image: The Datepicker with previous and next value]

Any idea on why it is changed? or How can I change it to old version?

(P.s : I currently use API 15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But after I changed my computer and moved project to new computer, I get an error on getChildAt(int)

Your code incorrectly assumed that the implementation of `DatePicker` would never change.

> Any idea on why it is changed?

Because Google wanted to change it.

> How can I change it to old version?

Find the source code to the old version and fork it to create your own `LegacyDatePicker` or some such. You would want [the implementation from Android 2.3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread/core/java/android/widget/DatePicker.java), I imagine.

The implementation of `DatePicker` is up to the Android framework, and it will vary over time. I would not be surprised if the next version of Android has yet another look.